# Honest verifier zero knowledge property for this protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, quadratic-residuosity, zero-knowledge

This is zero-knowledge proof that show x is not a quadratic residue.

[image]

I am trying to verify Honest verifier zero knowledge property.
My steps were these:
Let S be a simulator that does not know how to actually comute NQR(m, .)

1. Bob will choose a random $s$ and will send a $y$ according to the value of the coin
   b.
2. Now simulator does not actually know how to compute b' =NQR(m, y) - and I do not
   think that rewinding will be helpful - so he randomly outputs a $b \in \{0, 1\}$.
   Chances are $b=b'$ with probability 1/2.
   So basically S proves without the knowledge of the secret (function computation here) with propabillity $1/2 \geq 1/2$. So the protocol holds HVZK property.

Is my proof valid? Am I missing something?